# Fitty.js: how do I force a font size recalculation on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fitty

I'm using Fitty https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty to fit text into divs, but I can't get this particular instance to work.

In the `.title` div, Fitty works, though there is a bit of overfow issue.

But in the `.details` div, I'm using jQuery to force Fitty to recalculate on mouseover to fit the text, but the font stays at the minSize and overflows, or it doesn't grow to maxSize when there is less text; see images.

[image]
[image]

The issue could to be that Fitty doesn't fit text to the container height; see https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty/issues/9 . But I tried the various fixes in that bug thread in the Fiddle and couldn't get any of them to work.

How can Fitty correctly fit the text in `.details`? Does it need to be force recalculated? Is the container height or width the problem?

I'd like to stay with the current HTML markup, if possible, but using CSS Grid is possible.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2q9Lpya/1/ and Snippet below.

```js
fitty('.details', {
  minSize: 10,
  maxSize: 20,
});

   fitty('.title', {
 minSize: 10,
 maxSize: 24,
   });

jQuery('.kitten_container')
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    var fitties = fitty('.details');
    fitties[0].fit();
  });
```

```css
.outer_container {
  width: 300px
}

.kitten_container {
  border: solid 1px #e6e6d6;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 30%;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.details {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 50%;
  top: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.kitten_container:hover .details,
.kitten_container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.image_container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
}

.the-image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom_container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.year_and_award {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.author_name {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.title {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitty/2.3.7/fitty.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="kitten_container">
        <div class="image_container">
          <div class="the-image">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_container">
          <div class="year_and_award">2023 Kitten of the Year</div>
          <div class="author_name">Fuzzy</div>
          <div class="title">My Other Long Kitty Cat Life</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="kitten_container">
        <div class="image_container">
          <div class="the-image">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_container">
          <div class="year_and_award">2022 Kitten of the Year</div>
          <div class="author_name">Fluffy</div>
          <div class="title">My Life as a Cat</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely not your issue but I have the best luck with fully formed CSS like `overflow: hidden` make it `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: This is NOT a tool/plugin I have used but you may try unwrapping `<div class="overlay">
          <div class="details">L` to just be `<div class="details">L`

Comment: I did a 10 second site scan and see this https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty#do-not-upscale-text which sort of describes this issue (might be different cause)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the do-not-upscale-text and no luck. I don't think I can unwrap overlay because of the absolute position needed for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of all that positioning as hard to maintain.  I use `grid` and then simply put the overlay at the same place in the grid as the overlay container with `grid-area: herotop;` then.  I did also use some `display: grid; place-items: center;` to "super center" some content in that container in places.

I also changed the JavaScript to use the child element directly so the `[0]` is not needed and makes layout changes easier.

Forgive my change to `em` after I set body to `16px` font size as I find it easier to think in terms of `1em` rather than `16px`

Added a light border around the bottom just to show where it was visually and a new item with limited text to show it was scaling within the confines of the hero block.

```js
fitty('.overlay', {
  minSize: 8,
  maxSize: 18,
});

jQuery('.kitten_container')
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    const dt = $(this).find('.overlay').get(0);
    fitty(dt).fit();
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.kitten_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6em;
  grid-template-areas: "herotop" "herobottom";
  border: solid 1px #e6e6d6;
  padding: 0.635em;
  height: 17.5em;
}

.overlay {
  grid-area: herotop;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.details {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 13.125em;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  z-index: 999;
}

.kitten_container:hover .details,
.kitten_container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.image_container {
  grid-area: herotop;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 150px;
}

.the-image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom_container {
  grid-area: herobottom;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  padding: 0.625em;
  border: 1px solid #80808040;
}

.year_and_award {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.author_name {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.title {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitty/2.3.7/fitty.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center g-0">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="kitten_container">
        <div class="image_container">
          <div class="the-image">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum cheese bits dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_container">
          <div class="year_and_award">2023 Kitten of the Year</div>
          <div class="author_name">Fuzzy</div>
          <div class="title">My other Life as a Cat</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="kitten_container">
        <div class="image_container">
          <div class="the-image">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_container">
          <div class="year_and_award">2022 Kitten of the Year</div>
          <div class="author_name">Fluffy</div>
          <div class="title">My Life as a Cat</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="kitten_container">
        <div class="image_container">
          <div class="the-image">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="details">ittty bitty
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_container">
          <div class="year_and_award">2022 Hairball of the Week</div>
          <div class="author_name">Furr</div>
          <div class="title">Purr</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is a "hero"? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/heroes/ so you MIGHT be able to use the bootstrap `d-grid` etc. classes but I did not delve into that for this simple example here. Related jumbotron https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/

Comment: Thanks, and the grid-template CSS and HTML is interesting. But the main issue is that the font-size is not increased/decreased by Fitty or the function. Hairball of the Week does show a font-size of 20px, but the other two are 16px, but neither is one of the values of `minSize: 8, maxSize: 18,` in the Fitty function.

Comment: Something something about the mouse enter and it not retaining the values in the JS so I updated to use an object and re-use that both places; changed some markup to deal with the idiosyncrasies of the code - which to credit were noted on the github site